# Installing Samba

Tags: samba, ubuntu-11.10

I am setting up Samba on Ubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric) but the `/etc/init.d/samba` file is not being created. I've done this before and haven't had this problem. I uninstalled `samba`, `samba-common`, `smbclient`, and `swat` and reinstalled them but still have the same problem.

Ideas?

Comment: Are you installing it using `apt-get` or through Synaptic?

Answer (score 2):

Samba 3 consists of two separate daemons: `smbd`, handling SMB connections, and `nmbd`, handling NetBIOS name lookups. They have separate initscripts.

In addition, both initscripts have been converted from sysvinit to Upstart, so the correct command is **`start smbd`**, not `/etc/init.d/smbd start`.

<sub>(The third daemon, `winbind`, is in a separate package on Ubuntu.)</sub>